# React, passing state setter (useState) to child component with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having a hard time figuring out the types when passing the useState setter function to a child component.

I've tried to simplify to just the essential code below:

**parent**

```
function Parent() {    
  const [name, setName] = useState("Structured")
  ..
  return (
    <>
      <Child setName={setName}/>
    </>
```

**child**

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

function Child(setName: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>){
  return (
    <>
      <Input onChange={
        (value)=>{
          setName(value: SetStateAction<string>)
          console.log(value)
        }
      </Input>
    </>
```

On the parent I'm getting the following errors:

> Type "{ setName: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; }' is not
> assignable to type ' IntrinsicAttributes &
> Dispatch<SetStateAction'
> Property 'setName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Dispatch<SetStateAction>'.

On the child I'm getting:

> Argument of type
> "string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'SetStateAction'
> Type
> "string[]'
> is not assignable to type
> "SetStateAction'

Comment: Child(setName: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>) shoud be Child({setName: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>})

Answer (score 4):

Should be

```
function Child({ setName } : { setName: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>}){
```

`Child` component accepts props, which is an object, not just `setName` value

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with the help of `FC` from React, if you want for example to be explicit about the return as well:

```js
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, FC} from "react";

interface ChildPropsType {
  setName: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}
const Child : FC<ChildPropsType> = ({setName}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Input onChange={
        (value as string)=>{
          setName(value);
        }
      </Input>
    </>
  )
}
export default Child;
```

For the `onChange` part I'm a doing a type cast as I don't know how this `Input` looks like.